# Fsi fails to augment a type constructor - bug or feature?

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Let's take a *type augmentation abusive* F# script below:

```
type AugmentMe = val _i : int
type AugmentMe with member i.I = i._i
type AugmentMe with new(i) = { _i = i }
printfn "AugmentMe instance: %i" (AugmentMe(42).I)
```

that, when being interpreted as a whole, yields the expected `Fsi` output:

```
> 
AugmentMe instance: 42

type AugmentMe =
  class
    new : i:int -> AugmentMe
    val _i: int
    member I : int
  end
val it : unit = ()
```

Now, if we reset `Fsi` session and interpret the same script, but this time line-by-line, then `Fsi` fails to add the type constructor with the following diagnostics for the last two script lines:

```
> 
type AugmentMe =
  class
    val _i: int
  end
> 
type AugmentMe with
  member I : int
> 

~vs7894.fsx(3,30): warning FS0073: internal error: pop on empty stack during code generation, methodName = AugmentMe..ctor, m = C:\Users\gene\AppData\Local\Temp\~vs7894.fsx(3,29)-(3,39)

type AugmentMe with
  new : i:int -> AugmentMe
> 

~vs7894.fsx(4,35): error FS0039: The value or constructor 'AugmentMe' is not defined
```

After some googling the [following mentioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559699/cyclic-function-type-dependency-in-f) circa 2011 has popped up, but apparently the artifact still has place.

What gives? Should I report it to fsbugs?
Thank you.

Comment: looks like a bug to me.

Comment: An internal error is **always** a bug.